# Highlight matching part of string in TD when other TD is hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

If i mouse over a TD element i want to highlight part of the string in another TD. Example: If i mouse over **apple** i want to highlight the **apple** part of **applebanana**.

I tried several things but didn't get closer to any solution. Thank you for your help.

My Code up to now: Cannot use word param because it is undefined. this.innerText does not return "apple".
Also onMouseout the hightlighted part of the string gets deleted.

```
function hightlightInput(word){
    $(document.getElementById("testid")).html($(document.getElementById("testid")).html().replace(new RegExp("(apple)(?![^\">]*\"[^>]*>)", "i"), "<mark>$1</mark>"));
}

function resetHighlight() {
    $(document.getElementById("testid")).find("mark").replaceWith(function() {
        return $(document.getElementById("testid")).contents();
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td onMouseOver="hightlightInput(this.innerText)"onMouseOut="resetHighlight()">apple</td>
   <td id="testid">applebanana</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these situations, I always use a regexp and put the text in a `<mark>` element, which I remove later on.

You could then improve it by giving colors in and adding these as a style to the mark element, but by default it gives a yellow background to text (in most browsers). The mark element is easy to find back and usually doesn't get used for anything else, so its perfect for these things.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td id="change">applebanana</td></tr>
    <tr><td onMouseOver="highlightInput(this, this.textContent)"onMouseOut="resetHighlight(this)">apple</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

Here's a solution fully in native JS:

```
function highlightInput(element, word) {
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("(" + word + ")(?![^\">]*\"[^>]*>)", "i"), "<mark>$1</mark>");
}
function resetHighlight(element) {
    var marks = element.getElementsByTagName("mark");
    var marksLength = marks.length;
    for(var i = (marksLength - 1); i >= 0; --i)
    {
        element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(marks[i].innerText), marks[i]);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpgekko/LshW6/1/

---

Here's a solution using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library:

```
function highlightInput(element, word) {
    $(element).html($(element).html().replace(new RegExp("(" + word + ")(?![^\">]*\"[^>]*>)", "i"), "<mark>$1</mark>"));
}
function resetHighlight(element) {
    $(element).find("mark").replaceWith(function() {
        return $(this).contents();
    });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpgekko/LshW6/

I'll leave the adaptation to find all elements to highlight up to you, let me know if you need help with that. But it's probably just looking through the table for occurrences of the word if I read your question correctly.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the changes I made based on your answer. But it actually does nothing. I am at a loss here.

Comment: @user2196234 Sorry, my bad, there needs to be an extra `$(element).html()` around the replacing code to set the new value. See updated answer.

Comment: @user2196234 Also added a fully native solution, seeing how it wasn't a jQuery question.

Comment: I did that but it still does not work (updated question content). On another note: is it normal that alert(word) prints "undefined"?

Comment: @user2196234 If its within `highlightInput`, then no. That would mean the parameters aren't getting set properly.

Comment: It is within highlitInput. I now got it to "work" but it replaces the entire content with <mark>$1</mark> and not only the substring. also it includes $1 as literal not as a reference. I will update my question with my full code.

Comment: @user2196234 Without seeing more code, I can't say for certain what's up. As you can see in the fiddles, the snippets them self work.

Comment: @user2196234 I put your code in a jsfiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gpgekko/ra5wh/ (the only thing I changed was a line in `resetHighlight`). Seeing how you are using the jQuery solution, did you include the jQuery library on your page? Also, where do you put the JS code? Is it executed immediately or inside an event handler?

Comment: I am not using the jquery solution as far as I see. I now got the code to work but the problem remains that word is still undefined and i don't know why.

Comment: @user2196234 In your question you are showing the jQuery solution code. The solution involving `$` is the jQuery one (jQuery registers itself as `$` on the global namespace). The `word === undefined` issue is most likely caused by the placement of code. The functions need to be defined before the html element in the page. Don't put them in `onLoad` handlers or anything.

Comment: The js code is inside <script> tags above the <html> tag of my file. Might there be another solution to the problem?

Comment: @user2196234 Wait, above the HTML? You mean the table or the actual `<html>` tag? If its the later, its not going to work because its never going to get parsed. Put it inside the `<head>` element. You could try replacing `innerText` with `textContent`.